# How check if the sum of the values of two columns, in the same row have exactly 100 as result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, checksum

I have this problem in mysql (phpmyadmin).. I should want to check if the values of 2 columns do 100… for example I have this table

```
| BLABLABLA |         BLABLABLA | VALUE1 | VALUE2 |
```

and user want add this values(bla, bla, 20, 30)..
I would that 20 and 30 can't be added in this table because 20+30<>100..
my code is:

```
ALTER TABLE `partita` CHECK (`100` = (SELECT (`POSSESSO_PALLA_CASA`+`POSSESSO_PALLA_OSPITE`)                        FROM `partita`))
```

but naturally this was wrong.. how i can do? 
thank you all!!!

Comment: mysql doesn't support check constraints. use a pre-insert trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented MySQL doesn't support `CHECK` constraint. Per [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) it says:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines

You should rather use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger as an alternative like below

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER sumcheck_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON bla_table FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
IF (NEW.VALUE1 + NEW.VALUE2 <> 100) THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'can not insert data';
END IF   
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'can not insert data'; END' at line 2

Comment: Not sure but I don't see any issue in the posted trigger code of my head.